# Group by multiple columns on a single MySql stored procedure

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I have the below stored procedure which I use to show data on multiple ASP chart items.

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `GetChartApprovedData`(in siteValue varchar(45),
in skillValue varchar(100), in shiftValue varchar(100), in tmValue varchar(45), 
in grpmValue varchar(45), in dateValue date, in dateValue1 date)
BEGIN
SELECT count(agentlogin) AS totalApproved, shift AS Shift, skill AS Skill, tm AS TM, grpM AS GrpM
   FROM approved
   WHERE (sitevalue IS NULL
           OR site = sitevalue)
         AND (skillvalue IS NULL
               OR skill = skillvalue)
         AND (shiftvalue IS NULL
               OR shift = shiftvalue)
         AND (tmValue IS NULL
                OR tm = tmValue)
         AND (grpmValue IS NULL
                OR grpM = grpmValue)
         AND (dateValue IS NULL
                OR date BETWEEN dateValue AND dateValue1)
                group by shift, skill;
END
```

And when I use the above stored procedure to show the data in ASP chart I get the below result

[image]

Both the chart are giving the same grouping result. What I want is for the first chart I want it to group by shift and for the second chart I want it to be grouped by skill. Is it possible to achieve this without using separate stored procedure for both? Please let me know. Thanks in advance :)

```
private void GetChartData()
{
    string MyConString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["connStr"].ConnectionString;
    MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(MyConString);
    MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("GetChartApprovedData");
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    string siteValue = null;
    DateTime? dateValue = null;
    DateTime? dateValue1 = null;
    if (ddlSite.SelectedValue != null && ddlSite.SelectedValue != "0")
    {
       siteValue = ddlSite.SelectedValue;
    }
    if (ViewState["Date"] != null && ViewState["Date"].ToString() != "0")
    {
        dateValue = DateTime.Parse(ViewState["Date"].ToString());
    }
    if (ViewState["Date1"] != null && ViewState["Date1"].ToString() != "0")
    {
        dateValue1 = DateTime.Parse(ViewState["Date1"].ToString());
    }
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("siteValue", siteValue);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("dateValue", dateValue);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("dateValue1", dateValue1);
    cmd.Connection = con;
    con.Open();
    MySqlDataReader myread = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    while (myread.Read())
    {
        this.Chart2.Series["Series1"].Points.AddXY(myread["Shift"], myread["totalApproved"]);
        Chart2.Series["Series1"].IsValueShownAsLabel = true;
        Chart2.Series["Series1"].Label = "#VALY(#PERCENT)";
        Chart2.Series["Series1"].ToolTip = "Shift: #VALX \\nCount: #VALY";
        Chart2.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisX.LabelStyle.Interval = 1;
        Chart2.Legends.Clear();
        Chart2.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisX.MajorGrid.Enabled = false;
        Chart2.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisY.MajorGrid.Enabled = false;
        Chart2.Series["Series1"].Color = Color.DarkOrange;


        this.Chart1.Series["Series1"].Points.AddXY(myread["Skill"], myread["totalApproved"]);
        Chart1.Series["Series1"].IsValueShownAsLabel = true;
        Chart1.Series["Series1"].Label = "#VALY(#PERCENT)";
        Chart1.Series["Series1"].ToolTip = "Skill: #VALX \\nCount: #VALY";
        Chart1.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisX.LabelStyle.Interval = 1;
        Chart1.Series["Series1"].Color = Color.DarkOrange;
        Chart1.Series["Series1"].LabelBackColor = Color.White;
        Chart1.Legends.Clear();
        Chart1.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisX.MajorGrid.Enabled = false;
        Chart1.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisY.MajorGrid.Enabled = false;
   }
   con.Close();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way around your problem would be to do both queries inside your procedure (one to `GROUP BY` shift, and one to `GROUP BY` skill, and use a flag in the results to indicate if the result was data grouped by shift or skill:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `GetChartApprovedData`(in siteValue varchar(45),
in skillValue varchar(100), in shiftValue varchar(100), in tmValue varchar(45), 
in grpmValue varchar(45), in dateValue date, in dateValue1 date)
BEGIN
SELECT 'skill' AS type, count(agentlogin) AS totalApproved, skill AS Skill, tm AS TM, grpM AS GrpM
   FROM approved
   WHERE (sitevalue IS NULL
           OR site = sitevalue)
         AND (skillvalue IS NULL
               OR skill = skillvalue)
         AND (shiftvalue IS NULL
               OR shift = shiftvalue)
         AND (tmValue IS NULL
                OR tm = tmValue)
         AND (grpmValue IS NULL
                OR grpM = grpmValue)
         AND (dateValue IS NULL
                OR date BETWEEN dateValue AND dateValue1)
                group by skill;
SELECT 'shift' AS type, count(agentlogin) AS totalApproved, shift AS Shift, tm AS TM, grpM AS GrpM
   FROM approved
   WHERE (sitevalue IS NULL
           OR site = sitevalue)
         AND (skillvalue IS NULL
               OR skill = skillvalue)
         AND (shiftvalue IS NULL
               OR shift = shiftvalue)
         AND (tmValue IS NULL
                OR tm = tmValue)
         AND (grpmValue IS NULL
                OR grpM = grpmValue)
         AND (dateValue IS NULL
                OR date BETWEEN dateValue AND dateValue1)
                group by shift;
END
```

Then in your c# code you would change these lines:

```
    this.Chart2.Series["Series1"].Points.AddXY(myread["Shift"], myread["totalApproved"]);
    this.Chart1.Series["Series1"].Points.AddXY(myread["Skill"], myread["totalApproved"]);
```

to:

```
if (myread["Type"] == "shift") {
     this.Chart2.Series["Series1"].Points.AddXY(myread["Shift"], myread["totalApproved"]);
}
if (myread["Type"] == "skill") {
     this.Chart1.Series["Series1"].Points.AddXY(myread["Skill"], myread["totalApproved"]);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it is possible using a [Dynamic SQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html). We can create a query string, and then prepare and execute it. This will allow us to specify dynamic column name, which is not possible directly.

You will also need to use one more parameter to specify which column to use in `Group By`

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` 
  PROCEDURE `GetChartApprovedData`(in siteValue varchar(45),
                                   in skillValue varchar(100), 
                                   in shiftValue varchar(100), 
                                   in tmValue varchar(45), 
                                   in grpmValue varchar(45), 
                                   in dateValue date, 
                                   in dateValue1 date, 
                                   in groupByColumn varchar(64)) 
-- add extra in parameter, groupByColumn, to specify which column to group upon 

BEGIN

SET query_str = CONCAT('SELECT 
                          count(agentlogin) AS totalApproved, 
                          shift AS Shift, 
                          skill AS Skill, 
                          tm AS TM, 
                          grpM AS GrpM
                        FROM approved
                        WHERE (sitevalue IS NULL
                               OR site = sitevalue)
                          AND (skillvalue IS NULL
                               OR skill = skillvalue)
                          AND (shiftvalue IS NULL
                               OR shift = shiftvalue)
                          AND (tmValue IS NULL
                               OR tm = tmValue)
                          AND (grpmValue IS NULL
                               OR grpM = grpmValue)
                          AND (dateValue IS NULL
                               OR date BETWEEN dateValue AND dateValue1)
                        GROUP BY ', 
                        groupByColumn); -- concatenate the group by column param

-- prepare the query
PREPARE stmt FROM query_str;

-- execute the query
EXECUTE stmt;

-- Clear up
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;

END $$

DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: How do we get the value for 'groupByColumn'?

Comment: @prkash You pass it as a parameter to your stored procedure.

Comment: Then I will have to create separate mysql commands and pass parameters individually for each charts, it will be too many lines of codes.

Comment: @prkash what all parameters are there ?

Comment: I've just added the c# code to the question. So in myread if it reads skill column I want it to be grouped by skill and if it reads shift i want it grouped by shift column.

Comment: @prkash but at a time you want only single type of group, right ? I still cannot understand why my answer would produce more lines of code for you. Can you show (what you mean)!

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to reduse c# code size than you can use the stored procedure provided by Madhu Bhaiya  with the code bellow to achieve desired result:

```
    private void GetChartData()
    {
        string MyConString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["connStr"].ConnectionString;
        MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(MyConString);


        //PTK: TypeOfChartValue should be change with chart type you are using (I did not know what chart library you are using in your code
        Dictionary<string, TypeOfChartValue> charts = new Dictionary<string, Chart>()
        {
            { "shift", this.Chart2 },  //PTK: the first value here is a column name to use in group by , the second is the chart to fill with resulted data. this line means that the Chart2 must be filled with data grouped by  'shift'
            { "skill", this.Chart1 }  //PTK: the first value here is a column name to use in group by , the second is the chart to fill with resulted data. this line means that the Chart1 must be filled with data grouped by  'skill'
            //PTK: you can add here as many charts as you wish
        };
        foreach (string groupby in charts.Keys)
        {
            //PTK: TypeOfChartValue should be change with chart type you are using (I did not know what chart library you are using in your code
            TypeOfChartValue chart = charts[groupby];

            MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("GetChartApprovedData");
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            string siteValue = null;
            DateTime? dateValue = null;
            DateTime? dateValue1 = null;
            if (ddlSite.SelectedValue != null && ddlSite.SelectedValue != "0")
            {
                siteValue = ddlSite.SelectedValue;
            }
            if (ViewState["Date"] != null && ViewState["Date"].ToString() != "0")
            {
                dateValue = DateTime.Parse(ViewState["Date"].ToString());
            }
            if (ViewState["Date1"] != null && ViewState["Date1"].ToString() != "0")
            {
                dateValue1 = DateTime.Parse(ViewState["Date1"].ToString());
            }
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("siteValue", siteValue);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("dateValue", dateValue);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("groupByColumn", groupby);

            cmd.Connection = con;
            con.Open();
            MySqlDataReader myread = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            while (myread.Read())
            {
                chart.Series["Series1"].Points.AddXY(myread["Shift"], myread["totalApproved"]);
                chart.Series["Series1"].IsValueShownAsLabel = true;
                chart.Series["Series1"].Label = "#VALY(#PERCENT)";
                chart.Series["Series1"].ToolTip = "Shift: #VALX \\nCount: #VALY";
                chart.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisX.LabelStyle.Interval = 1;
                chart.Legends.Clear();
                chart.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisX.MajorGrid.Enabled = false;
                chart.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisY.MajorGrid.Enabled = false;
                chart.Series["Series1"].Color = Color.DarkOrange;

            }
            con.Close();
        }
    }
```